# python 3 get the column name depending of a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So i have a pandas df (python 3.6) like this

```
index   A   B   C  ... 
  A     1   5   0
  B     0   0   1 
  C     1   2   4
 ...
```

As you can see, the index values are the same as the columns names.

What i'm trying to do is to get a new column in the dataframe that has the name of the columns where the value is > than 0

```
index   A   B   C  ... NewColumn
  A     1   5   0       [A,B]
  B     0   0   1       [C]
  C     1   2   4       [A,B,C]
 ...
```

i've been trying with iterrows with no success

also i know i can melt and pivot but i think there should be a way with apply lamnda maybe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If new column should be string compare by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) with [`dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) product with columns, last remove trailing separator:

```
df['NewColumn'] = df.gt(0).dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
print (df)
   A  B  C NewColumn
A  1  5  0      A, B
B  0  0  1         C
C  1  2  4   A, B, C
```

And for lists use `apply` with lambda function:

```
df['NewColumn'] = df.gt(0).apply(lambda x: x.index[x].tolist(), axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  NewColumn
A  1  5  0     [A, B]
B  0  0  1        [C]
C  1  2  4  [A, B, C]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df['NewColumn'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(x[x.gt(0)].index),axis=1)

   A  B  C  NewColumn
A  1  5  0     [A, B]
B  0  0  1        [C]
C  1  2  4  [A, B, C]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) to check which values are greater than `0` and [`.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html#pandas.DataFrame.dot) to obtain the corresponding columns. Finally `.apply(list)` to turn the results to lists:

```
df.loc[:, 'NewColumn'] = df.gt(0).dot(df.columns).apply(list)

       A  B  C  NewColumn
index                    
A      1  5  0     [A, B]
B      0  0  1        [C]
C      1  2  4  [A, B, C]
```

---

*Note*: works with single letter columns, otherwise you could do:

```
df.loc[:, 'NewColumn'] = ((df.gt(0) @ df.columns.map('{},'.format))
                         .str.rstrip(',').str.split(','))

       A  B  C  NewColumn
index                    
A      1  5  0     [A, B]
B      0  0  1        [C]
C      1  2  4  [A, B, C]
```